# How can i take the value of the specific option?

Tags: jquery

i have this code :

```
function select(cities, country) {
    $('<div class="btn-group "><button type="button" id="forecast" 
    data- toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="forecast" 
    class="btn btn-primary  pull-right" >Show Me The Forecast</div>').insertAfter('.btn-group');
    $('#cities').html(' <label for="cities">Select City</label>
    <select name="cities" id="city" class="form-control">' +
        '<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>' +
          cities.map(function (city) {
              return '<option value="' + city + '">' + city + '</option> ';
          }).join('') + '</select>'
    );
    var city = $("#city option:selected").val();
    console.log(city);
}
```

i want to take specific value of the above select element but every single moment it takes the first value and stores it to the `city` variable

Comment: Not really clear what this code should do or what you are asking. Show where `select()` gets used also. See [mcve] and [ask] then edit the question with proper details

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted the results in this demo:

```js
select(['city1', 'city2', 'city3'], 'country1');

function select(cities, country) {
    $('<div class="btn-group "><button type="button" id="forecast" data- toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="forecast" class="btn btn-primary  pull-right" >Show Me The Forecast</div>').insertAfter('.btn-group');


    $('#cities').html(' <label for="cities">Select City</label><select name="cities" id="city" class="form-control">' +
        '<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>' +
        cities.map(function(city) {
            return '<option value="' + city + '">' + city + '</option> ';
        }).join('') + '</select>'
    );
    
    var city = $('#city option:selected').val();
    console.log(city) // initially selected city (none)
    $("#city").on('change', function() {
        city = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        console.log(city); // changed option for new selected city
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cities">
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
</div>
```